# Null en modelo multinomial con calculo de K-S en R

Tags: r, regresión-lineal, modelos

Estoy intentando hacer un modelo de regresión logística multinomial que me seleccione el mejor modelo de entre todos los posibles.

Me esta resultando imposible y al haber buscando en tantas IA, ya que esta desnaturalizado.

Estuve leyendo en el foro y realmente no hay nada ni parecido. Yo tengo una variable principal ( RISK) y quiero ver que modelo se ajusta mejor con sus otras 13 de respuesta.

Esta en el df numérico ( TrainFIN)y ninguna es binaria. He probado todo menos binaria porque no puedo.

Muchas gracias por vuestra ayuda, poca ya es mucho

```
hacer_modelos <- function(modelos, train_data, max_time_seconds = 6000) {
  lista <- as.data.frame(modelos)
  temp <- data.frame(id = NA, Gini_train = NA, Gini_test = NA, test_signos = NA, test_correlaciones = NA)

  variables <- names(train_data[, !colnames(train_data) %in% c("ID", "Quick_Ratio", "RISK_0", "LPS")])
  combinats <- combinations(variables, 5)
  combinats <- as.data.frame(t(combinats))

  for (j in 1:(nrow(lista))) {
    aux <- as.data.frame((as.data.frame(lista[j,])))

    for (i in 1:(ncol(aux))) {
      colnames(aux)[i] <- as.character(aux[1, i])
    }

    ind <- names(aux[, 1:ncol(aux) - 1])
    temp2 <- data.frame(id = lista[j, "id"], Gini_train = NA, Gini_test = NA, test_signos = NA, test_correlaciones = NA)

    # Medir el tiempo de ejecución
    time_result <- system.time({
      tryCatch({
        setTimeLimit(cpu = max_time_seconds, transient = TRUE)
        Logit_model <- multinom(factor(RISK) ~ ., data = train_data[, c("RISK", ind)])
        pr_logit_train <- predict(Logit_model, newdata = train_data[, c("RISK", ind)], type = "probs")
        # Imprimir información adicional
        print(summary(Logit_model))
      }, error = function(e) {
        print(paste("Error in model ", j, ": ", conditionMessage(e)))
      })
    })

    # Verificar si se excedió el tiempo máximo permitido
    if (time_result["elapsed"] > max_time_seconds) {
      warning(paste("Execution of model ", j, " exceeded the maximum allowed time."))

      # Otras acciones si se excede el tiempo 
    } else {
      colnames(temp2) <- colnames(temp)
      temp <- rbind(temp, temp2)
    }
  }

  return(temp[-1, ])  
}

# Ejecutar el código
t <- proc.time()

# Train es entrenamiento
combinats5 <- combinations(names(TrainFIN), 5)
modelos5 <- hacer_modelos(combinats5, TrainFIN, max_time_seconds = 600)

# Imprimir resultados
print(modelos5)

# Imprimir tiempo de ejecución
print(proc.time() - t)

best_model <- modelos5[which.max(modelos5$tu_criterio_de_selección), ]
```

Comment: ¡Hola @Carlos! Para poder atender a tu consulta es necesario que seas más concreto en tu pregunta: cuál es el error, dónde encuentras el problema, . . .